# Postgres - For some reason, not pulling based on date

Tags: postgresql

I for some reason am having an issue with this.  YES it seems to be a simple issue, but man, I'm frustrated.

I'm trying to run

```
Select * from
    dialer.data_hub_lead_responses
where CAST(created_at as DATE)  = '2017-11-20'
Order by created_at asc
```

and get no results.  Coming with no surprise, I can pull this on TONS of our other tables, but for some reason, a handful of tables don't pull anything.

And yes, data is there.

[image]

Comment: Maybe date format of that you are passing isn´t correct. Check date format of table column.

Comment: what makes you think data is there?..

Comment: `'2017-11-20'` is a string. You may want to change this to `date '2017-11-20'`, which is a date.

Comment: And I prefer `date_trunc('day', created_at)` over `CAST(created_at as DATE)`, because it says "I have a datetime and want to get the date without time from it", rather than "I have a date in a datetime variable and want to interpret its content as date". Both work, but the latter statement is not correct, because there is no mere date in the datetime column. I am even inclined to consider it a minor flaw that the cast doesn't crash (as does `cast('123x' as int)` because the string content is not a mere int).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use ::date

```
Select * from dialer.data_hub_lead_responses where created_at::DATE = '2017-11-20' Order by created_at asc
```

Comment: `created_at::DATE` is exactly the same thing as `CAST(created_at as DATE)`